# Printing direct descendants of a category with WP_Query

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop

So I'm having trouble printing just the direct children of a category on a page. Here's my code:

```
 $category_id = get_cat_ID('destinations');
 $args = array('child_of'   => $category_id);
 $categories = get_categories($args);
 $args = array (
    'category__and'                    => $categories->$cat_ID
);
   $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($recent_posts->have_posts())  : while ($recent_posts->have_posts()) : $recent_posts->the_post();
```

This code prints every category regardless of who's the parent. If I change this:

$recent_posts = new WP_Query('cat=43');
It prints out the right category, but also all of it's children and children's children(obviously). I just want the directly related children printed. I went ahead and echoed a serialize($categories) which returned the correct array. However when I serialize($args) AFTER the 2nd declaration, it gives me:

```
a:1:{s:13:"category__and";N;}
```

This is definitely weird. Why on Earth is it returning an 'N' for $categories->$cat_ID? I've been trying to do this all day and have been unsuccessful. I've also tried to find another method to do what I want but nothing came up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

```
 child_of 
    (integer) Display all categories that are descendants (i.e. children & grandchildren) of the category identified by its ID. There is no default for this parameter. If the parameter is used, the hide_empty parameter is set to false.
```

And...

```
parent  
    (integer) Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category identified by its ID. This does NOT work like the 'child_of' parameter. There is no default for this parameter. [In 2.8.4]
```

So, first, you are using the wrong argument if you only want the immediate decendants. You need:

```
$args = array('parent'   => $category_id);
```

Secondly, `get_categories` will give you an array of objects so you will need something like this to extract the IDs.

```
$cats = wp_list_pluck($categories,'cat_ID');
$args = array (
  'category__and'                    => $cats
);
```

Giving you:

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('destinations');
$args = array('parent'   => $category_id);
$categories = get_categories($args);
$cats = wp_list_pluck($categories,'cat_ID');
$args = array (
  'category__and'                    => $cats
);
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```